# Command-query segregation principle for an authenticator

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc

The `Authenticate` method violates the command-query segregation principle, right? How can I adhere to the command-query segregation principle here?

```
public class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    public bool Authenticated
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; }
    }

    public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        var authenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
        if (authenticated)
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
        return authenticated;
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Mark Seemann](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/3878/mark-seemann) recently [blogged](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/11/cqs-versus-server-generated-ids/) about this.

Comment: Where does the `IAuthenticator` come from? I cannot find it in MSDN.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca `IAuthenticator` is an interface that I defined. It is a *header interface*.

Comment: Can't you just make `Authenticate()` return `void` and then use `Authenticated` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's been several days and this question has not been answered, I will give it a go. I'm saying this not because making `Authenticate` follow Command-Query Separation Principle is hard, but rather I think this design may indicate a more serious problem with security configuration, and I'm not up to date with ASP.NET.

### Command Query Separation

> The Authenticate method violates the command-query segregation principle no?

Since you seem to be familiar with Fowler's terminology, let's look at [his definition of **Command/Query Separation**](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html).

> The fundamental idea is that we should divide an object's methods into
>   two sharply separated categories:
>
> - Queries: Return a result and do not change the observable state of the system (are free of side effects).
> - Commands: Change the state of a system but do not return a value.

Since in this case `Authenticate` definitely changes state, specifically the session state by setting a cookie, it is a command and should not return a value. You can achieve this, as suggested by @svick:

> you [can] just make `Authenticate()` return `void` and then use `Authenticated` instead.

That is:

```
public void Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    // unused `authenticated` can be inlined
    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password))
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
}
```

And why not following CQS is a problem? Because `Authenticate()` returns a value, it is not immediately clear to the reader of the code if the writer of the code *just* checks the validity of the username/password pair or does what it does now, thus makes understanding the code harder.
Similarly someone looking at the `IAuthenticator`, which should look like this as you stated that it's a [Header Interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/HeaderInterface.html):

```
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    bool Authenticated {get;}
    bool Authenticate(string username, string password);
    void Logout();
}
```

faces similar dilemma: Do I use `Authenticate` to *just* check for the validity of username/password, or does it do something more?

There is also another problem with returning `bool` from `Authenticate(...)`, because `Authenticate` is an imperative word, and an `Autheticated` getter (read-only property) is also present, it could be that `bool` return value is an error code for the `Authenticate` command, that is you MUST check it immediately after calling the method and do something with it other than what you would to with the return value of `Authenticated`. For example `Authenticated == false` implies wrong password whereas `Authenticate(username, password) == false` could mean "Membership database is down". Of course [error codes are a no-no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Now I should also state that apparently MS APIs do not always follow CQS principle, as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

But **Command Query Separation** should also make us reevaluate if the method underneath follows **Single Responsibility Principle**. A method like this would be used like this:

```
if (Authenticator.Authenticate(credentials)) {
   // continue to secured content
} else {
   // return to login page
}
```

We see that the `if` in `Authenticate` is duplicate, and increases the complexity of the code unnecessarily:

```
if (Authenticator.Validate(credentials)) {
   Authenticator.Login();
   // continue to secured content
} else {
   // return to login page
}
```

This division requires some further points to be made:

- Currently `Authenticator` has two separate responsibilities: Checking if username/password pairs are valid, and keep user logged in across multiple requests.
- `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` requires username, but you do not use it after checking whether username/password is valid, i.e. `Authenticator.Login` does not need it. 
  However your current implementation would need the username to be passed to `Authenticator.Login`, therefore **you would need to modify the interface because of an implementation detail**. That is `IAuthenticator` would not be a proper abstraction over `FormsAuthentication`.
- This is rightly so, because even though `Authenticator` pretends it's not a static class, it does not encapsulate it's own state. You can observe this, as it does not have any state of its own and all the methods it calls from `FormsAuthentication` are static methods:

  ```
  // Note that the no-argument constructor hides its dependency
  // to `Thread`, `HttpContext` or something. 
  IAuthenticator authenticatorOne = new Authenticator(); 
  IAuthenticator authenticatorTwo = new Authenticator();
  authenticatorOne.Authenticate("Alice", "4L1(3'5 p455\/\/0rD");
  authenticatorTwo.Authenticate("Bob", "808'5 p455\/\/0rD");
  authenticatorTwo.Logout();
  ```

  As seen here, having multiple instances of `Authenticator` (in a request? thread?) does not make any sense.

### Naming Side Note

It is hard to parse `Authenticator.Authenticated` mentally, as the object of the `Authenticate` is absent. For example in `IIdentity.IsAuthenticated` it is clear that the *identity* is the authenticated thing. If we change members of `IAuthenticator` as follows:

```
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    bool Validate(string username, string password);

    bool SomeUserIsLoggedin {get;}
    void Login();
    void Logout();
}
```

Now it is clear that `Login`/`Logout` are opposite commands. `SomeUserIsLoggedin` checks whether `Login` has been called and `Logout` has not been called yet. And `Login`/`Logut` having no parameter matches with *Some User* being the object of *Is Logged In*, which altogether indicate that you do not care who the user is and care just that he logged in.

This way `Validate` is more clearly seen to be separable from the rest of the `IAuthenticator` members.

### Header Interfaces Side Note

If you mean *Header Interface* as in the [Fowler's dichotomy of Header/Role interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html), it is rather an *anti* pattern, as they violate the ISP:

> Robert Martin talks about this topic as the Interface Segregation
>   Principle: role interfaces follow that principle but header interfaces
>   do not.